# The servers certificate could not be trusted while connecting with Realm Studio

Tags: realm

When I am try to connect the ROS using Realm Studio its says "The servers certificate could not be trusted"

Below is the screen-print :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried trusting the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue as you. But after reading  [Realm Studio does not trust SSL certificate of Realm Cloud on Linux #898](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/issues/898)   issue

> Clicking "Reconnect, trusting the certificate" reloads the window but the same error is shown, endlessly. This was fixed with #905 but the issue of not automatically trusting the Realm Cloud certificate persists.
>
> Users can now (once again) choose to trust the a certificate, but the issue remains that Studio does not automatically trust the Realm Cloud certificates of Realm Cloud.

I upgraded the realm studio to version `2.7.0` and attempted to reconnect. It worked.